# Magento 2 : Guest Add to cart items not showing

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php

I am creating a cart as a guest cart via magento API and adding items via magento APIs to it and its working fine and the API is showing items in the guest cart in POSTMAN.

The issue is that the items are not showing in the browser on the cart page which is `'/checkout/cart/'` URL.

How can I be able to see the items of the guest cart in the browser?

**Note:** I am using the default Luma theme.

Comment: are you getting any error in error log file or in console. If you got then please send this error.

Comment: @RiteshSantra there is not an error, Just the items in the cart are not showing in the browser

Comment: No, error will be there in console or in another side. You need to find this first. or if you give me this link I can try to find this.

Comment: @RiteshSantra i have edited my question please check it. I am creating a cart and adding items to it via the APIs, But its not showing with me in the browser on the cart page.

Comment: In that case item will not be shown because magento will not recognize that the api create cart guest visitor user in showing in website. means that the two visitor is same. because there are no user id.

Comment: @RiteshSantra then how will i be able to see the guest cart items?